# Where do I find the "Sports you play" and "Favorite Teams" and "Favorite Athletes" information?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Using the FB C# SDK v5.xx and trying to find out about a user's "sports you play", "favorite teams" and "favorite athletes" information.

Tried query on the USER table but perhaps I did not have the correct column names.
Used the following column names but got back null, as you can see.
"sports":null,"favorite_teams":null,"favorite_athletes":null

The FB developer doc on the USER table does not list those columns.

Anyone know how to find that information?

Answer (score 1):

`favorite_teams` and `favorite_athletes` is `null` because facebook deprecated this fields.

You can check in documentation from below link
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/